# Video.js + YouTube and resolution selector

Tags: video.js

I'm trying to make it work with videojs-youtube but to no avail. Tips or code, anyone?

Plugins:

https://github.com/kmoskwiak/videojs-resolution-switcher

https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube

Answer (score 1):

The videojs-youtube team flagged this as out of scope for their tech plugin: https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube/issues/312

There is some talk about how you could go about writing a separate plugin for this: https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube/issues/326#issuecomment-155442215

Sorry!